# How do I add a #process callback to a fieldset form element without overwriting the existing callbacks?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the following code.

```
$form['my_fieldset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('My Title'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#access' => TRUE,
  '#process' => array('my_callback_function'),
);
```

If a fieldset is collapsible, it gets two callbacks at some point later.

```
form_process_fieldset | (Callback) form_process_fieldset();
ajax_process_form | (Callback) ajax_process_form();
```

They aren't added to the array with my callback function. If I look at the form array, there is only my callback; so, there is no collapse functionality.

I tried to avoid that by adding the callback in `hook_form_alter()`, but this is too early; the callback functions are still not there.

```
$form['my_fieldset']['#process'][] = 'my_callback_function'; //Not working eather
```

So where is the right place to add a `#process` callback to my own form element, so it gets added as last callback in the callback array, or at least is not destroying the callbacks implemented by this specific form element itself?

I do some calculations in the callback to set `#access = FALSE` for this fieldset under certain conditions. This works fine, but maybe this is the wrong way to do it.

The documentation on [#process](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#process) says:

> You will probably want to add to the existing array rather than writing over it, so don't follow this usage example exactly.

The documentation is not very helpful, I don't follow but there is no info how it is done right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a #process function to a form element, the default ones defined from [hook_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7) are not added. Using `hook_form_alter()` to add a #process function doesn't change the result, as `hook_form_alter()` is invoked before the default #process functions are added to the form element. This happens in [form_builder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7), which uses the following code.

```
 // Use element defaults.
  if (isset($element['#type']) && empty($element['#defaults_loaded']) && ($info = element_info($element['#type']))) {
    // Overlay $info onto $element, retaining preexisting keys in $element.
    $element += $info;
    $element['#defaults_loaded'] = TRUE;
  }
```

If `$element['#process']` is already set, it doesn't get overriden by `$info['#process']`, which means the default functions are not added.

What you can do is invoke the default #process function from the one you define. If `mymodule_process_function()` is the function you add, it should contain code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_process_function($element, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($element['#type']) && ($info = element_info($element['#type'])) && isset($info['#process'])) {
    foreach ($info['#process'] as $process) {
      $process($element, $form_state);
    }
  }
  // ...
  return $element;
}
```

If the #process function is necessary in any form where a fieldset is present, then you can implement [hook_element_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/7) to alter the information returned from [system_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_element_info/7) about the fieldset form element.

```
  $types['fieldset'] = array(
    '#collapsible' => FALSE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE, 
    '#value' => NULL, 
    '#process' => array('form_process_fieldset', 'ajax_process_form'), 
    '#pre_render' => array('form_pre_render_fieldset'), 
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('fieldset'),
  );
```

The alternative that requires less code to be written is to add a #after_build function to the fieldset. #after_build functions are functions that are called after the #process ones, receive `$element`, and `&$form_state` as argument, and need to return `$element`. As `system_element_info()` doesn't set any #after_build function, there is less code to execute.
For compatibility with any module that implement `hook_element_info_alter()`, and which could alter the fieldset definition, code similar to the one I shown before should be used also for the #after_build property.

Comment: Thanks! The hook_element_info_alter suggestion worked out for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$fieldset_info = element_info('fieldset');
$fieldset_process = array_merge($fieldset_info['#process'], array('my_callback_function'));

$element['my_fieldset'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Name'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#process' => $fieldset_process,
);
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers,